# How to resolve latest DNS CName results via powershell

Tags: powershell, dns

I am trying to resolve the latest DNS CName using the following powershell script. However due to the DNS server caching, I am getting the cached host name which is not the latest CName.
Is there anyway to avoid this and get the latest results? (as in digwebinterface.com)

Afterwards I am invoking a third party DNS management API, which will modify or create DNS CName mapping. For this I need the latest dns data.

```
#resolve the dns host name
$resolvedCName = Resolve-DnsName -Name $vanityHostName -DnsOnly -Type CNAME | 
Select-Object -First 1 -Property Name,NameHost  

write-host $resolvedCName.NameHost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the late response, finally I decided to go with the DNS solution (Ansible Tower) API to get the CName for the hostname.

Powershell Resolve-DnsName -DnsOnly take some time to propagate the DNS. However my release pipeline expect the propagation to be done within few minutes. It's actually doing couple of changes to the host name.

The use of -DnsOnly switch will resolves the query using only the DNS protocol. Even this takes some time to resolve latest DNS results. Therefore I had to go with the API and it worked without any latency issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a PowerShell issue or error. Its an environment condition.

Why are you not just clearing the cache as part of what you are doing?

Are you saying, that the DnsClientCache cmdlets or Ipconfig -FlushDNS are not giving you what you are after?

[The Clear-DnsClientCache cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/clear-dnsclientcache?view=win10-ps) deletes all the contents of the DNS client cache. Running this cmdlet is equivalent to running ipconfig /flushdns.

```
Get-Command -Name Clear-DnsClientCache | Format-Table -AutoSize

<#
CommandType     Name                   Version    Source 
-----------     ----                   -------    ------  
Function        Clear-DnsClientCache   1.0.0.0    DnsClient 
#>


# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Clear-DnsClientCache -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Clear-DnsClientCache).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Clear-DnsClientCache -Full
Get-help -Name Clear-DnsClientCache -Online
Get-help -Name Clear-DnsClientCache -Examples


ipconfig /?

<#
USAGE:
    ipconfig [/allcompartments] [/? | /all | 
                                 /renew [adapter] | /release [adapter] |
                                 /renew6 [adapter] | /release6 [adapter] |
                                 /flushdns | /displaydns | /registerdns |
                                 /showclassid adapter |
                                 /setclassid adapter [classid] |
                                 /showclassid6 adapter |
                                 /setclassid6 adapter [classid] ]

where
    adapter             Connection name 
                       (wildcard characters * and ? allowed, see examples)

    Options:
        ...
       /flushdns        Purges the DNS Resolver cache.
       /registerdns     Refreshes all DHCP leases and re-registers DNS names
        …
#>
```

Comment: The OP clearly said "DNS *server* caching", not "DNS *client* caching". I think @Kasunu is asking how to tell the DNS server in the query NOT to get the answer from it's own cache, but rather go up the DNS tree and start at the root.

Answer (score 0):

For recurring DNS testing that tou need to have change when the responsible nMe server changez the address, query the responsible namd server directly.

Clearing the client side cache will not effect `Resolve-DNSName ]` as it id an `NSLookup` equivalent and so queries the remote server directly instead of using the host's normal resolver mechanism.

So, you should locate the name servers for `$VanityHostName` uding a half dozen methods, such as arin or dnstoolbox, then specify the name servers for the site as the server in your query as below (4.2.2.2 is a placeholder for the address of the sites' s name server.)

```
  #resolve the dns host name
  $resolvedCName = Resolve-DnsName -Name $vanityHostName -DnsOnly -Type CNAME -Server '4.2.2.2' | Select-Object -First 1 -Property Name,NameHost  

write-host $resolvedCName.NameHost
```